# Redirect from a conversation

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to call the action of a controller, I am using botman studio and the Laravel framework:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Conversations;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Incoming\Answer as BotManAnswer;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Question as BotManQuestion;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Actions\Button;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\OutgoingMessage;
use App\config\botman\config;
use redirect;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class sss extends Conversation
{
 
  /**
   * Start the conversation.
   *
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function run()
  {

 $this->in();

  }


public function in() 
    {

     $this->say('Hello !');
     Redirect::action('PdfController@invoice');

        
    }
  

}



?>
```

This is the line that I need to modify:

> Redirect::action('PdfController@invoice');

It is a chatbot therefore it has that syntax (Botman studio)

Comment: declare route and then put return redirect(route('route_name'))

Comment: if you just want to call the method rather than redirecting make controller object and call the method like $ctrl = new PdfController() , $ctrl->invoice